# unable to access private repos with oauth access token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, github-api, django-allauth

i have created a Oauth github app and Oauth works fine. but i want to access the all repos(including  private) with the access-token i get during Oauth. i have tried with personal access token and i am getting all the private reops. why its not working with Oauth access-token ?

**Scops**

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'github': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'user',
            'repo'
        ],
    }
}
```

regarding the env. i am using dj-rest-auth to authenticate with Github and get the access-token.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=*****&scope=repo
for some reason django setting wasn't working for social auth providers. so I try with URL parameters and it's working. thank you ;)